# Octopress style not applied to new blog post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, octopress

I am using Octopress (based on Jekyll) for a blog. On my latest post, the style has not been applied. The top of the HTML file looks like this, when I viewed the source:

```
<p>I wrote a <a href="http://www.github.com/bjcubsfan/passphrases">program</a> 
that generates passphrases. <a href="../passphrases">Passphrases are a better 
alternative</a> to commonly-used, hard-to-remember but easy-to-guess passwords 
(&#8216;eyebrow favor advancing homeland&#8217; versus 
&#8216;Tr0ub4dor&amp;3&#8217;). The python program randomly picks four
```

My previous post has normal HTML headings, specifies a CSS stylesheet, etc.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Passphrases - B. J. Potter</title>
<meta name="author" content="B. J. Potter">


<meta name="description" content="The xkcd comic criticizing the state
 of passwords made sense to me. Why are we subject to password requirements
 that point us toward hard-to-remember &hellip;">


<!-- http://t.co/dKP3o1e -->
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="/atom.xml" rel="alternate" title="B. J. Potter" type="application/atom+xml">

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.bjpotter.com/passphrases">
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I have tried regenerating (rake generate) the site, removing the latest post and creating it fresh, but the outcome is the same.

What could be causing this? How could I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this might be caused by missing YAML Front Matter. Are you sure your latest post is getting it? Can you show us your Markdown source?

For troubleshooting, you could try changing first your post, and then the relevant layouts -- such as to see if they're really being used during this post's compilation.

Comment: Thanks! I had a typo right at the top of the yaml front matter. I had `layout: pos` instead of `layout: post`. It seems like this should throw an error.

Comment: What version of Jekyll are you using? I thought they displayed an error when an invalid layout was being used...

Comment: I am using Jekyll version 0.12.0, which seems to be out of date. I am not sure if Octopress is compatible with a newer version.

Comment: Hm, ok. You should really open an issue on their GitHub Issue Tracker regarding this. :)